# Mint-17.2 --Sudo apt-get update error package error 404

Tags: linux-mint, apt-get

Following the steps to install xplico (a program):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.xplico.org/ $(lsb_release -s -c) main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 791C25CE
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xplico
```

When I'm at the step 3 (update) I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.xplico.org/dists/rafaela/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.xplico.org/dists/rafaela/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is a problem because I need to update it successfully before being able to install it. I tried it on my kali machine which worked perfectly. Now, I tried to install the xplico_1.1.0_amd64.deb (22.1 MB) but when I doubleclick it, it says I dont have the right version of python (3.3) BUT I have the version 2.7 and the version 3.4 .... Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: 404 error is an answer provided by the server, that mean "not found" that folder or files do not exist

Comment: Francisco Tapia I know that but my question would be, what are the alternative if there is one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to install software from a repository for Ubuntu, but you are using Linux Mint and so the first command created a false entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Instead of "rafaela" (the Mint code name) the line for your repository should include the code name of the Ubuntu version your Mint release is based on (that is apparently Ubuntu 14.04, "trusty").

Replace in `/etc/apt/sources.list` rafaela with trusty and try again.

It will probably allow you to download [this package](http://repo.xplico.org/pool/main/x/xplico/xplico_1.1.0-14.04_amd64.deb), which will probably work for you.

Comment: doesnt work: still a 404 page not found, I'll try again with my kali machine to see what is the comand used

Comment: Have you tried installing the package (the one I have linked to in my answer) directly?

Comment: just by double clicking it?

Comment: Downloading it and installing via `dpkg -i`

Comment: YAY!! works like a charm (for the moment) before accepting the answer, can you please answer my 2 questions?: 1) in the source.list, there is a copy of the same line 6 times with the rusty, do I delete some and do I place it back to rafaela? 2) Can you tell me in which case I can use this answer / which package to look for to install ? thank you very much :D

Comment: The only line in `source.list` where you should replace `rafaela` with `rusty` is the one for `http://repo.xplico.org` everywhere else you should use `rafaela`. If there is more than one line with `http://repo.xplico.org` then you could probably delete all but one of them. I am not quite sure what you are asking in 2)

Comment: hey hum, when I was supposed to install it via the apt-get, there were some extentions that were required, any suggestion on that? because the application doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install -f`

Comment: does nothing, do you know how to fix the apt-get update? because there is still the 404 page not found

Comment: Yes I noticed xD already changed but the problem is everytime I try to apt-get update, it adds a line with rafaela for xplico

Comment: Why? Are you perhaps repeating all the commands from your question? The first two lines are only necessary once.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas pointed out, the link in your `sources.list` is incorrect. If you check http://repo.xplico.org/dists/ you'll see the supported distros:

```
  Name                    Last modified      Size  Description
  Parent Directory                             -   
  natty/                  28-Sep-2013 13:45    -   
  oneiric/                28-Sep-2013 13:45    -   
  precise/                28-Sep-2013 13:45    -   
  quantal/                28-Sep-2013 13:45    -   
  raring/                 03-Nov-2013 01:33    -   
  saucy/                  26-Dec-2013 07:47    -   
  trusty/                 25-Apr-2014 06:51    -
```

So your link in `sources.list` should include one of the above distros to be able to `apt-get update`.

**Note**: please make sure your distro is compatible with one of the above mentioned before running `apt-get update` and `apt-get install`!

Comment: actually it is not, but do you know if kali linux is compatible for any of them?